# Is there any way to track the Wi-Fi connection of the device during communication

Tags: iphone, ios, connection, wifi, handle

Currently I'm developing an application which can send multiple files to other device over Wi-Fi using [**bonjour**](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) service same as **developer.apple [Wi-Tap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html)** application did. Only one difference is ,I'm sending files where **Wi-Tap** sending strings.

Now I would like to handle the Wi-Fi connection issues like connection loss in my application.

I can handle the `NSStream` `Errors` through  `handleEvent` delegate for below cases

```
 NSStreamEventErrorOccurred 
 NSStreamEventEndEncountered
```

However I'm Unable to find the Wi-Fi connection loss through this `delegate`. So the possible solutions in my mind is using the [**Reachability**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class for checking the wi-fi connection in a background thread. However it's a bad practice and it consumes more battery power of device.

So is there any other way to track the Wi-Fi connection of the device during the file transfer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around is to use use **NSNetService**

As this is just a service publishing tool it won't interfere in your data transfer so you just have to use

```
-(void)publishNetwork
{
//---publish the service---
netService = [[NSNetService alloc] 
              initWithDomain:@"" 
              type:BonjourServiceName 
              name:@"" 
              port:portNo];
netService.delegate = self;
[netService publish]; 

}
```

You have to run this in

```
[netService scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

if Wifi is on then this will be fired

```
- (void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender
 {
    NSLog(@"Service did publish:%@",sender);

 }
```

if there is no wifi

```
-(void)netService:(NSNetService *)aNetService didNotPublish:(NSDictionary *)dict 
 {
   NSLog(@"Service did not publish: %@", dict);
}
```

These are the delegates of NSNetService you can refer the library .
This is just a way around your problem hope it helps.

Comment: what happens if wi-fi is interupted after the `netServiceDidPublish` is fired ?

Comment: Make a netservice object which will be used just to check the wifi and keep publishing it in the back ground after a time interval,so the time your wifi connection gets lost *didNotPublish * delegate will be called,and as i said that this is just a publishing tool it won't interfere in you data communication. I know this is not the best solution.

Comment: I didn't get any other answer, so I'm accepting your answer. Also I temporarily fixed it by checking the wifi connection periodically using a timer.